# Excel Convert Formula to User Function

Tags: excel, vba, string, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

I built a formula the spits off an email address with number from another group of numbers.  For example I have thousands of the following types of strings:

2064439215Wilma33@flintstone.com
Result after Formula:  Wilma33@flintstone.com

My Excel formula which works perfectly is:
=RIGHT($A$6,LEN($A$6) LEN(LEFT(A$6$,
(MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(VALUE(MID($A$6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A$6))),1))),0))-1))).
With special notes on how I handled VALUE (changed it to VAL) and the INDERECT function ( is bracketed its calc [ xxx ], Here is the broken user function that I think should work, however;  it just does not work.

```
  Function Test(Cell_Addrs As Range)
    
     NewString = Right(Cell_Addrs, Len(Cell_Addrs) - Len(Left(Cell_Addrs, _ 
    (Application.WorksheetFunction.Match _
    (True, IsError(Val(Mid(Add_Rss, Application.WorksheetFunction.Row _
    ([INDIRECT("1:" & Len(Cell_Addrs))]), 1))), 0)) _ 
    - 1)))

    Test = NewString

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Val()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) function to get the preceding number and just replace it with an empty string.

> The Val function stops reading the string at the first character that
> it can't recognize as part of a number.

```
Public Function ToEmail(rng As Range) As String
    ToEmail = Replace(rng.Value, Val(rng.Value), vbNullString)
End Function
```

Comment: I will try to figure a way to get your beautiful function to apply to this in case that comes up:  Wilma33@Finstome.com2065551212

Comment: @RWB - might be worth updating your question to something a little more detailed - eg "need to extract a [x-digit?] number from a string" and show examples of inputs and wanted outputs

Comment: I wrote a function the handles the numbers on the right by reversing the string, posting to a WS-cell and then reversing the sting to it original order.  It is very "un-elegant", but it the only way I could use your (Kosta K.) Function since the function requires a range object.   I have tried researching changing a string to a range object, but that looks like a nightmare.

Comment: All of this complexity is caused because of no spaces between characters so I also wrote another function as a helper which put spaces between numbers and alpha characters.  again, another long solution, but works

Comment: @RWB if you want to change the function argument to string, rename `Range` to `String` and remove the `.Value` property. Not sure if this is what you're looking for.